# Converting my spatial coordinates into a sf object in R

Tags: r

I'm quite new to R and currently stuck on the following task. I have spatial data in the following format:

```
 lat             long
1 49,6837508756316 8,97846155698244
2 49,9917393661473  8,2382869720459
3  51,308416699361 12,4118696787101
4 50,7048668720388 6,62725165486336
```

...
and so on. It's a pretty large data set.

I've been advised to convert my data set into sf data to properly work with it. Can somebody help my with that? I think one problem might also be, that the decimal mark is an `,`.

Thanks for your help guys!

Comment: If you are reading these data from an external file, you can just use the `read.csv2` function which can handle European style decimals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the data is in a `data.frame` called `sf`:

```
sf <- data.frame(lat=c("49,6837508756316","49,9917393661473","51,308416699361","50,7048668720388"),long=c("8,97846155698244","8,2382869720459","12,4118696787101","6,62725165486336"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

The problem is, that the entries are characters, so you have to convert them to `numeric`. This can be done via `as.numeric`, but this function expects the decimals to be seperated by a dot `.`, hence you have to convert the comma to a dot and then call `as.numeric`. The conversion can be done using the function `gsub`.

```
sf$lat <- as.numeric(gsub(",",".",sf$lat))
sf$long <- as.numeric(gsub(",",".",sf$long))
```

If you have many columns and you dont want to copy-paste the above for every column, I would suggest you to use:

```
sf[] <- lapply(sf, function(colValues) as.numeric(gsub(",",".",colValues)))
```